# Curvilinear abscissa

Tags: parametrization

The curve arc length does not depend on the given parameterization of the this curve, because there are infinite ways to represent it according to the parameter t. For example

$$\vec{f}(t) = [t,t^2] \; ; \; \vec{g}(t) = [t^3,t^6]$$

they are both parametrizations of the same identical parabola. The arc length L, considering a regular curve in a range $[a, b]$, depends on a parameter $s$ that takes the name of curvilinear abscissa. Taking as an example a generic curve, and calculating the length of the arc between $0$ and $t$

$$s = s(t) = \pm \int_{0}^{t} ||r'(u)|| du$$

Forgive me the question, but in the texts I have never found anything exhaustive: why in the last formula, $||r||$ is written in function of another variable, in this case $u$?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Another than $s$ or another than $t$ or another than what?

Comment: another tthan $t$: the original vectorial function is $\vec{r}(t)$

Comment: Never mind: write $t$ for $u$.

Comment: If it were written as
$$
\int_0^t \left| \left| r'(t) \right| \right| dt
$$
then it would be a bit confusing as to whether $t$ refers to the upper limit or the integration variable. So it's just for clarity.

Comment: Thank you @MattiP.!